# How do I compare against the current week using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I compare an SQL Server date column against the current week?

For instance:

```
WHERE [Order].SubmittedDate = *THIS WEEK*
```

Comment: `[Order].SubmittedDate BETWEEN @StartOfThisWeek AND @EndOfThisWeek`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could convert your date to a week number and compare this to the week number from the current date. Likewise, you'll need to compare the year as well, so that you don't get last year's weeks.

```
WHERE DATEPART(wk, [Order].SubmittedDate) = DATEPART(wk, GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(yy, [Order].SubmittedDate) = DATEPART(yy, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Be aware you may notice a performance hit as this is a non-sargable condition so prevents best index use. see http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/t_sql_where_p2.aspx

Comment: +1 Nice tip. It may look simpler but it's not necessarily good performance.

Comment: do you have a way of making this perform faster?

Comment: @Andy - yes, see my answer. Basically, don't wrap the field being queried in a function call. Instead, you work out the start and end date of the period you're interested in and query with that date range

Comment: I would advise caution with the above approach. Try replacing getdate with the dates between the 30th Dec 2015 and the 2nd Jan 2016 for example. There's a logic error there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are meaning always "this week" and there are no records with Submitted dates in the future, which I imagine could be the case you can do:

```
WHERE [Order].SubmittedDate >= DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) -1), GETDATE())
```

If dates do go into the future, the full restriction to this week is:

```
WHERE [Order].SubmittedDate >= DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) -1), GETDATE())
    AND [Order].SubmittedDate < CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(dd, (8 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())), GETDATE()), 120) AS DATETIME)
```

I'd strongly recommend using a clause based on a start and end date like this, as it will allow efficient index use so should perform better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE [Order].SubmittedDate BETWEEN
      DATEADD(d,   - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + 1, GETDATE()) AND
      DATEADD(d, 7 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())    , GETDATE())
```

Maybe this can run faster, as doesn't needs to be evaluated everytime:

```
DECLARE @StartDate   DATETIME, 
        @EndDate     DATETIME 
SELECT  @StartDate = DATEADD(d,   - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + 1, GETDATE()),
        @EndDate   = DATEADD(d, 8 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())    , GETDATE())

-- // Strip time part, so week starts on Sunday 00:00
SELECT  @StartDate = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@StartDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME),
        @EndDate   = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@EndDate   AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
...
WHERE [Order].SubmittedDate >= @StartDate AND [Order].SubmittedDate < @EndDate
```

Comment: Technically you can miss records using this (slim chance) - what about records created in that last second (e.g. 23:59:59.500)? Hence I always prefer to use a >=.... AND <.... approach using 00:00:00 of the next day as the < end date

Comment: It's because I've seen instances where this has actually produced incorrect results in the wild and is quite easy to overlook when trying to find an issue so was worth noting.