# Filtering columns based on a date in a field for current week, past weeks, and future weeks

Tags: sql-server, datetime, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

**Example Table:**

(**Column Heading**) Total Interviews of everyone --- (**Row Heading**) Interview Requested

(**Column Heading**) Number of interviews this week -- (**Row Value**) Count all the dates scheduled this week that have the status: "Interview Requested" e.g 4

(**Column Heading**) Number of interviews next week -- (**Row Value**) Count all the dates scheduled next week that have the status: "Interview Requested" e.g 6

First of all i'll like to aploigise about my makeshift table, it seems that i cant use pictures since im a new member.

I am also new to using reportbuilder and sql and have been trying to figure out how i can count the amount of dates that fall between certain date ranges in a report.

Like ive stated in the makeshift field called "Number of interviews this week" I wish to count all the dates scheduled for the current week, the week after, the week before and so on based on a date field. I then plan to break this table down to show all the interviews a single person has schedueled.

The issue I am having is that there will be many dates spanning different months/days. So Im not sure how i can represent this with DateDiff or other date features, because the table is meant to be a live representation of the current interviews.

Is what i'm trying to do even possible using report builder?? If so any tips would be great, if not then thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

As Requested Dataset Fields:

[UserName] (User table), [InterviewStatus] (Interview table), [DateUpdated] (Interview Table)

Those are the main ones that will be used in the report

Comment: Yup the 2012 version, im using the reporting services which gives me report builder to use.

Comment: How is your dataset? Updating your question with your dataset fields would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the generic select statement from your interview table filtering in the where clause for dates between the beginning of the current week and the end of the next.

Then the two fields would be a sum of 1 if the date falls within the current week or next.

**EDIT:**
Example below will give the number of dates within this week. Taken from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2063817/1685810):

```
Select InterviewStatus,
       Sum(Case when DateUpdated >= DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) -1), GETDATE())
                     AND DateUpdated < CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(dd, (8 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())), GETDATE()), 120) AS DATETIME)
                Then 1
                Else 0 end) 
          as NumberInCurrentWeek
From InterviewTable
Where DateUpdated >= DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) -1), GETDATE())
      AND DateUpdated < CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(dd, (8 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())), GETDATE()), 120) AS DATETIME)
Group by InterviewStatus
```

This just needs to be tweaked to your exact circumstance. For example alter the 8 by 7 will capture the current fortnight.

Then produce a simple table based on the query.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thanks for reply will give it a tweak now to fit it to the report i need to create.

Comment: Was just wondering if i wanted the range to be within 3 weeks, how would i represent this using this code? Would i just have to change the 8 to the number 6??

Comment: The 8 would become 8 + 14.

Comment: ahh i see now im starting to get your logic, thanks for getting back to me as well as helping me i think this will work for what im trying to do so im going to mark you as an answer.

Comment: I hope I've explained enough. Please let me know if you wanted more :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to count the number of columns of each field, you can use the sql statement `COUNT()` see [COUNT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp).

You can do the common query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(fieldName1), COUNT(fieldName2), ... , COUNT(fieldNamen) FROM <tableName>
```

Also try to show your codes so that your question will be more clarified.

Comment: Well the code would be:

    SELECT [tblInterviews.Date] FROM [tblInterviews] WHERE [tblInterviews.Status] = 'Interview Requested'

From there i want to count the dates that fall between the current week, then the next field in the right i want to count all the interviews that are scheduled next week (not including the current week)